# Apache - Python not executing

Tags: python, apache

I am having difficulty in getting Python to execute on my Apache web server.

My file looks like this

```
#! /usr/bin/python2.6
# enable debugging
import cgitb
cgitb.enable()

print "Content-Type: text/plain\r\n\r\n"
print "Hello World!"
```

I have enabled permissions for CGI execution and Python addHandler in `http.conf`

Apache is serving exactly what you see above.

Any ideas?

Comment: What difficulty are you having? Does it give you an error, or what is the problem?

Comment: Apache just serves the plain text, it has't been executed

Comment: The expected output of your code would be `Content-Type: text/plain` followed by two line breaks, and then `Hello World!`... what are you expecting?

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to enable mod_python

Comment: I am expecting exactly that, however Apache is just serving an exact copy of the python.

Comment: Is the CGI file itself executable?

Comment: The code compiles and works to my expectations.